# Why was this comment-flag declined?

Tags: discussion, flagging

I flagged [this comment](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/44736/how-to-cleanly-slice-hard-boiled-eggs/44747#comment64107_44747) as not constructive, since it doesn't contribute anything useful to future readers.

Why was my flag declined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured there was marginal value because the same user also posted the accepted answer. She's basically saying, yeah, there's a trick you can use to make this work with a knife, but I admit that even though I know that, I still have the (mostly) single-purpose tool that makes it extra easy.

Comment: A visitor can see that there are multiple solutions to given question. Someone saying that the second answer is valid too, isn't that useful. I still believe it should be removed, but anyway.

Comment: I'm not saying this is the most useful comment ever, but I think it has some amount of value. I completely agree with you that even without this, users could see that both answers exist, and that from the upvotes they could tell that both answers are valid, but that's not the value I'm saying the comment provides. If it were just a generic "+1 good answer" I would have deleted it, but it's very slightly more.